# What class of weapon is a flame thrower?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-purge-anarchy

In the Purge movie series, part of the rules of the purge are that

> Weapons of class 4 or lower are allowed but weapons of class 5 or higher are restricted.

After the commencement in "The Purge: Anarchy" we then see a montage of people with their weapons getting ready to purge and one of them is carrying a flame thrower

[image]

**I'm not an expert but aren't flamethrowers considered a class 5 weapon?**

Comment: Is it even regulated? I don't think it's *technically* a weapon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication (since it doesn't seem to have been explicitly stated in the film or any of the associated media) is that a class **5** weapon is something that is *non-directional and indiscriminate*. This would logically exclude the use of chemical weapons, nuclear weapons, biological weapons, high-explosive weapons and those with a long-lasting effects such as cluster munitions and dirty bombs.

Everything below that seems to be fair game including [flash grenades, miniguns, flamethrowers](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/The_Purge:_Anarchy) and [small anti-personnel grenades](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cscSg.jpg).